# Communication protocol analysis via microcontroller board

Tags: microcontroller, analysis, protocol

I have an idea for my master's thesis.

I want to make a communication protocol analyzer and monitor the data on a PC via software I coded.

For the first stage, I need a kind of data acquisition system like below:

[image: block diagram]

The communications bus I am interested in has 2 MBps bitrate, and Manchester coding (±5V differential voltage.)

I have no experience in high speed communication signal processing. What do you suggest for this task? Should I use some kind of ADC/transceiver or process the data directly via microcontroller with high sampling rate? In that case, is there any microcontroller you could propose with high msps?

By the way, writing ADC may cause misunderstanding. Scope of my evaluation is Manchester-high, Manchester-low and non-data (means no 1 or 0.)

Comment: You need to think a lot more about your requirements before selecting parts. What kind of "protocol analysis" are you doing? Do you care about analog voltages or just 1s and 0s? How deep will your samples be (how many bits in one acquisition)? Can you reliably extract the clock from the data? This is your project, you need to think about these things and draft your detailed requirements.

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. "Scope of my evaluation is manchester-high, manchester-low and non-data" -> my aim at this sentence is I care only logic values. As you said, just 1s,0s and non-datas. There will be no external clock data. My purpose is transmit the raw data to PC and after, create clock data in acquired data via software running on PC. By the way, thanks for your reply.

Comment: What devices use that communication, what communication it is? Realistically an USB logic analyzer costs about $20 and free open source software can be used to look at the waveforms and export it as raw data or CSV so you can import it to other programs or write one yourself to analyze it.

Comment: Isn't this just a bus pirate?

Comment: Getting megabit scale data from an MCU back into a PC isn't trivial.  As already mentioned a basic CY7C68013A logic analyzer will do this off the shelf; at least start there.  If you decide you really need analog there are boxes misleading sold as "scopes" which feed a couple  of ADC's into one.

Comment: This protocol could be MIL-STD-1553. Is this true?

Comment: You have given us some physical layer requirements. Are there any other layer requirements? These may be crucial in determining the overall approach.

Comment: it makes me wonder if the bus pirate was someone elses masters thesis,